# Does $\mathbb{R P}^n \times \mathbb{R P}^n$ admit a metric with positive sectional curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

My riemannian geometry professor gave us the following exercise.

Let $M = \mathbb{R P}^n \times \mathbb{R P}^n$, where $\mathbb{R P}^n$ is the $n$-dimensional projective space. Show that $M$ does not admit a metric with positive sectional curvature.

I was able to prove the result in the case $n$ is odd: In this case, $\mathbb{R P}^n$ is orientable and therefore $M$ is orientable. If $M$ admits a metric with positive sectional curvature then by the [Synge theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synge%27s_theorem) $M$ must be simply connected, which is not the case because $\pi^1(M) = \mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z$.

> How do I prove the result if $n$ is even?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $n$ even. Then $M$ is non-orientable and has positive sectional curvature. Consider the orientable double cover $\hat M \rightarrow M$ and pull back the Riemannian metric to $\hat M$. Then $\hat M$ has positive sectional curvatures and by Synges theorem $\hat M$ is simply connected. This implies that $\pi_1(M)=\mathbb{Z}/2$, which is wrong.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: can I apply a similar argument to $M=\mathbb{S}^m \times \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$?